# Cannot connect to WikiJS running in Docker via HTTPS

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, docker, https

I have a new WikiJS installation on a DigitalOcean droplet (using the marketplace image). I cannot access the site via HTTPS, either with the domain or IP address, but HTTP is fine.

I get a pretty generic `Unable to connect` error displayed in Firefox. It appears the underlying error message is `NS_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, but I can't actually see any sort of response.

As far as I can tell there's no firewall rules blocking anything, the Docker reverse-proxy is running and listening on port 80:

`ps aux`:

```
root       24755  0.0  0.2 1148340 2864 ?        Sl   15:26   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 80 -container-ip
root       24760  0.0  0.2 1148340 2920 ?        Sl   15:26   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 80 -container-ip 172.
```

Below is the output from `docker logs wiki`. I note that there's two lines about the HTTP server running, but nothing for HTTPS, however I don't know how I would go about enabling or disabling that (I haven't done anything special, literally just installed from the image).

```
2023-12-09T15:27:00.083Z [MASTER] info: =======================================
2023-12-09T15:27:00.087Z [MASTER] info: = Wiki.js 2.5.300 =====================
2023-12-09T15:27:00.087Z [MASTER] info: =======================================
2023-12-09T15:27:00.088Z [MASTER] info: Initializing...
2023-12-09T15:27:01.800Z [MASTER] info: Using database driver pg for postgres [ OK ]
2023-12-09T15:27:01.808Z [MASTER] info: Connecting to database...
2023-12-09T15:27:01.852Z [MASTER] info: Database Connection Successful [ OK ]
2023-12-09T15:27:03.533Z [MASTER] warn: Mail is not setup! Please set the configuration in the administration area!
2023-12-09T15:27:03.759Z [MASTER] info: Loading GraphQL Schema...
2023-12-09T15:27:06.173Z [MASTER] info: GraphQL Schema: [ OK ]
2023-12-09T15:27:06.738Z [MASTER] info: HTTP Server on port: [ 3000 ]
2023-12-09T15:27:06.784Z [MASTER] info: HTTP Server: [ RUNNING ]
2023-12-09T15:27:07.234Z [MASTER] info: Telemetry is active: [ OK ]
2023-12-09T15:27:07.340Z [MASTER] info: No new analytics providers found: [ SKIPPED ]
2023-12-09T15:27:07.431Z [MASTER] info: Loaded 21 authentication strategies: [ OK ]
2023-12-09T15:27:07.476Z [MASTER] info: No new comment providers found: [ SKIPPED ]
2023-12-09T15:27:07.509Z [MASTER] info: No new editors found: [ SKIPPED ]
2023-12-09T15:27:07.604Z [MASTER] info: No new loggers found: [ SKIPPED ]
2023-12-09T15:27:07.705Z [MASTER] info: No new renderers found: [ SKIPPED ]
2023-12-09T15:27:07.756Z [MASTER] info: No new search engines found: [ SKIPPED ]
2023-12-09T15:27:07.833Z [MASTER] info: No new storage targets found: [ SKIPPED ]
2023-12-09T15:27:07.835Z [MASTER] info: Checking for installed optional extensions...
2023-12-09T15:27:07.858Z [MASTER] info: Optional extension git is installed. [ OK ]
2023-12-09T15:27:07.874Z [MASTER] info: Optional extension pandoc was not found on this system. [ SKIPPED ]
2023-12-09T15:27:07.889Z [MASTER] info: Optional extension puppeteer was not found on this system. [ SKIPPED ]
2023-12-09T15:27:07.892Z [MASTER] info: Optional extension sharp was not found on this system. [ SKIPPED ]
2023-12-09T15:27:07.902Z [MASTER] info: Authentication Strategy Local: [ OK ]
2023-12-09T15:27:09.639Z [MASTER] info: (COMMENTS/DEFAULT) Initializing...
2023-12-09T15:27:09.640Z [MASTER] info: (COMMENTS/DEFAULT) Initialization completed.
2023-12-09T15:27:09.651Z [MASTER] info: (SEARCH/POSTGRES) Initializing...
2023-12-09T15:27:09.660Z [MASTER] info: (SEARCH/POSTGRES) Initialization completed.
2023-12-09T15:27:09.709Z [MASTER] info: (STORAGE/GIT) Initializing...
2023-12-09T15:27:09.711Z [MASTER] info: (STORAGE/GIT) Checking repository state...
2023-12-09T15:27:10.013Z [MASTER] info: (STORAGE/GIT) Listing existing remotes...
2023-12-09T15:27:10.030Z [MASTER] info: (STORAGE/GIT) Purging existing remotes...
2023-12-09T15:27:10.099Z [MASTER] info: (STORAGE/GIT) Setting SSL Verification config...
2023-12-09T15:27:10.168Z [MASTER] info: (STORAGE/GIT) Setting SSH Command config...
2023-12-09T15:27:10.239Z [MASTER] info: (STORAGE/GIT) Adding origin remote via SSH...
2023-12-09T15:27:10.305Z [MASTER] info: (STORAGE/GIT) Fetch updates from remote...
2023-12-09T15:27:11.652Z [MASTER] info: (STORAGE/GIT) Checking out branch main...
2023-12-09T15:27:11.696Z [MASTER] info: (STORAGE/GIT) Performing pull rebase from origin on branch main...
2023-12-09T15:27:12.967Z [MASTER] info: (STORAGE/GIT) Performing push to origin on branch main...
2023-12-09T15:27:13.936Z [MASTER] info: Purging orphaned upload files...
2023-12-09T15:27:13.939Z [MASTER] info: Syncing locales with Graph endpoint...
2023-12-09T15:27:13.942Z [MASTER] info: Fetching latest updates from Graph endpoint...
2023-12-09T15:27:13.985Z [MASTER] info: Purging orphaned upload files: [ COMPLETED ]
2023-12-09T15:27:14.145Z [MASTER] info: Fetching latest updates from Graph endpoint: [ COMPLETED ]
Loading configuration from /wiki/config.yml... OK
DB_PASS_FILE is defined. Will use secret from file.
2023-12-09T15:27:14.477Z [JOB] info: Rebuilding page tree...
2023-12-09T15:27:14.758Z [MASTER] info: Pulled latest locale updates for English from Graph endpoint: [ COMPLETED ]
2023-12-09T15:27:14.769Z [MASTER] info: Syncing locales with Graph endpoint: [ COMPLETED ]
2023-12-09T15:27:16.042Z [JOB] info: Using database driver pg for postgres [ OK ]
2023-12-09T15:27:16.251Z [JOB] info: Rebuilding page tree: [ COMPLETED ]
```

I'm at a bit of loss on what else to even try to find out what the problem is... Any suggestion of even things to look at would be much appreciated.

Comment: By default web servers use port 80 for plain http and port 443 and a certificate https. It looks like you've only configured plain http.

Comment: How would I go about setting that up? I'm using a pre-configured image of WikiJS (in Docker). I didn't have to do anything using the same image previously, I don't know why this would be different or how to go about that. The documentation (https://docs.requarks.io/install/config) says that the image comes with the following pre-installed: "... OpenSSH with UFW Firewall preconfigured for SSH, HTTP and HTTPS".

Comment: `docker port wiki` gives:
`3000/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:80`,
`3000/tcp -> :::80`,
`3443/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:443`,
`3443/tcp -> :::443`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve this. I'm still none the wiser as to what caused it, but I found that the config.yml file was referencing SSL_ACTIVE, and a bunch of other environment variables regarding SSL setup (see these docs: https://docs.requarks.io/install/config#lets-encrypt).

However, none of those variables were actually present (I checked by running docker exec -it wiki bash then printenv to see the environment variables in the docker container). My assumption is that because SSL_ACTIVE was undefined, WikiJS doesn't start the 443 listening service.

So I changed the config.yml file (using docker cp) to the correct values and then after restarting the HTTPS listener started and everything worked as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into similar issue. I'm a little confused as to how you've resolved this.  Do you have time to expand on what you mean by  you did a docker cp? I thought whenever you changed that host copy of the config file, it automatically updated the copy in the container. Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, this shouldn't be an answer, but a comment :-)

Comment: Hi. I know... but I can't seem to make comments on other people's answer...  I get "You must have 50 reputation to comment" when I tried so I just added an answer hoping it gets picked up by @WSC

Comment: I used `docker cp` to copy the config.yml file out of the docker container directory, edited the config.yml to change the undefined env variables to whatever they should be, then copied the edited config.yml back into the docker container's directory. I don't know if that's the best way to solve the problem, but it's what worked for me.